# Como cambiar el orden de una lista en Java?

Tags: java, lista, spring

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual lleno la lista **formaDePago** 
 con los datos cantidadPago y IdPago que me regresa un servicio, esa lista se la seteo a otra lista que tengo en mi clase form para que se muestre en pantalla

```
private void obtienePago(final CotizacServiceDto cotizacion,
        final ContratacionInternetForm form) {

    final List<FormaDePagoDto> formaDePago = new LinkedList<FormaDePagoDto>();

    for (final CotizaPagosServiceDto pagos : cotizacion.getCotizaPagosServiceDto()) {
        final FormaDePagoDto formaDePagoDto = new FormaDePagoDto();
        formaDePagoDto.setCantidadPago(Double.parseDouble(pagos.getPagoTotaSinImpuestoMonLocal()));
        formaDePagoDto.setIdFormaPago(pagos.getCotizacionFormaDePagoServiceDto().getId());
        formaDePago.add(formaDePagoDto);
    }
    form.setFormaDePago(formaDePago);
    System.out.println("FORMA DE PAGO::" + form.getFormaDePago());


}
```

y
 esto es lo que me regresa

```html
[cantidadPago=187.92,idFormaPago=A], 
[cantidadPago=2255.05,idFormaPago=M], 
[cantidadPago=375.84,idFormaPago=S], [cantidadPago=751.68,idFormaPago=T]]
```

y lo que quiero hacer es que el pago mensual sea el ultimo que muestre, o sea que quede A, T, S y M
Como puedo cambiar ese orden?

Comment: No entiendo cual es el criterio de la ordenación que pides "A, T, S, M". ¿M significa "mensual"? Y el resto? No creo que puedas hacer esto a no ser que lo elabores manualmente. Es decir insertar los objetos en el orden deseado. O añadir otro campo en FormaDePagoDTO que te sirva para la ordenación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase `Collections` y su metodo `sort` junto con una clase de ordenación que tendras que crear tu.

**Clase que ordena**

```
public class OrdenacionPropia implements Comparator<FormaDePagoDto> 
{ 
    @Override
    public int compare(FormaDePagoDto a, FormaDePagoDto b) 
    { 
        // Aquí rellenar con la lógica de ordenación 
    } 
}
```

**Logica en tu código**

```
private void obtienePago(final CotizacServiceDto cotizacion,
    final ContratacionInternetForm form) {

    final List<FormaDePagoDto> formaDePago = new LinkedList<FormaDePagoDto>();

    for (final CotizaPagosServiceDto pagos : cotizacion.getCotizaPagosServiceDto()) {
        final FormaDePagoDto formaDePagoDto = new FormaDePagoDto();
        formaDePagoDto.setCantidadPago(Double.parseDouble(pagos.getPagoTotaSinImpuestoMonLocal()));
        formaDePagoDto.setIdFormaPago(pagos.getCotizacionFormaDePagoServiceDto().getId());
        formaDePago.add(formaDePagoDto);
    }
    // Aquí ordenamos
    Collections.sort(formaDePago, new OrdenacionPropia()); 
    form.setFormaDePago(formaDePago);
    System.out.println("FORMA DE PAGO::" + form.getFormaDePago());
}
```